# Undefined data after responseJson is entered into state [] in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, api, rest

I have a problem here, namely when I do the Post API and add console.log (responseJson) the data appears and its contents are (app_uid and app_number). But when I enter the API data into the dataApp [] state and I try console.log (this.state.dataApp), no data appears.

Here is a piece of script from its post API function:

```
 onTask = (pro, tas) => {
        fetch('https://bpm.***********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/cases/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'pro_uid': pro,
            'tas_uid': tas,
          }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson); //here the data appears
          this.setState({
            dataApp: responseJson,
          });
          console.log(this.state.dataApp); //but here does not appear any data
        });
```

Hopefully I can find a solution here, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

## `this.setState` is an asynchronous function.

Meaning - in your example, that you won't see its result on the next line where you console log it, because it is not yet done.

Try the following:

```
this.setState({
  dataApp: responseJson,
}, () => console.log(this.state.dataApp)); // console.log inside a callback
```

To understand why it works inside a callback, and not in the next line, take a look at this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and this [React Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: After I tried this, still not showing any data, even I tried only console.log ("data will appear here") <- This console does not appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

setState() is an **async** call in React. So you won't likely get the updated state value in the next line. You need to use the **callback handler** to get the updated value.

```
 onTask = (pro, tas) => {

        //Code you need to add
         var that = this;
         
        fetch('https://bpm.***********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/cases/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'pro_uid': pro,
            'tas_uid': tas,
          }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson); //here the data appears
         that.setState({
            dataApp: responseJson,
          }, () => {
    console.log("dataApp: ", that.state.dataApp);
   });
  });
```

Comment: After I tried this, still not showing any data, even I tried only console.log ("data will appear here") <- This console does not appear on the screen.